# What would the following code 'Thread | ->' do in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, threadpool

I can't figure out what this code does here. The best I can tell is | is the bit-wise OR and -> is for a lambda, but still can't make sense of it as a whole.

```
pipe = Thread | -> (p) do
       end
```

Comment: In ruby the code does "NoMethodError: undefined method `|' for Thread:Class" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code doesn't do anything yet. It's a correct (but kinda weird) syntax, and the defined lambda doesn't do anything.

`|` isn't bit-wise OR, it's a method name of the `Thread` class, for the [`ruby-thread`](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread) gem:

```
require 'thread/pipe'

p = Thread |-> d { d * 2 } |-> d { d * 4 }
p << 2

puts ~p # => 16
```

But you're right though, it's possible to call then method `|` without using a `.` between `Thread` and the method name because Ruby's syntax allows code like `2 | 3` as a sugar for `2.|(3)`.

Without the gem, Ruby complains about a `NoMethodError`. To play a bit with the syntax, you could try:

```
class Thread
  def self.|(some_proc)
    some_proc.call("some_param")
  end
end

pipe = Thread | -> (p) do
  puts "Inside a proc, called from 'Thread.|' with parameter #{p}"
end
```

It outputs:

```
Inside a proc, called from 'Thread.|' with parameter some_param
```

Another way to write the call would be :

```
pipe = Thread.|( lambda{|param| puts "Inside a proc, called from 'Thread.|' with parameter #{param}"} )
```